# How does Lucky Break work?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, divine

I have a problem to understand how [this spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=430) works.

The spell description says:

> Reroll the saving throw and use the better result. You then become temporarily immune for 10 minutes.

But there is no duration assigned. So would I have to cast the spell after I rolled a bad saving throw? Or do I have to cast this spell beforehand so that it triggers. But how many hours before do I have to cast the spell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Lucky Break is a Reaction

> **Cast** [Reaction] verbal; **Trigger** You fail (but don't critically fail) a saving throw.

You generally get one [Reaction](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=442) per round, refreshing at the start of each of your turns. You use Lucky Break in response to the Trigger, using that one Reaction. Other Reactions include [Attack of Opportunity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=8) (for those that have it) and [Champion Reactions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Causes.aspx).

Reaction **Triggers** are slightly different than [Spells that you set a trigger](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=301) for such as Magic Mouth. You can note the difference in the Action type for using the spell (typically, spells are Reactions or Two Actions, but there are a number of 1 and 3 Aciton spells, and a few variable action ones). Reaction spells *always* follow the rules on Reactions, and take up your Reaction for the round, never your turn's Actions.

Comment: It may be good to note that this is different from the [spell triggers](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=301) discussed in the rules for spellcasting, or at least, I think it is and it may be the cause of the confusion. The example spell they give is the Magic Mouth